# How to calculate attributable percentage variability

Tags: regression, logistic, predictive-models, variability

I'm running some analyes on a project to understand variations in mortality using a dataset with patient and hospital level variables in Stata 18.

I am looking to calculate the percentage of the variability in outcome explained when by specific group of variables (patient-level, hospital-level).

Here is my model:

logistic mortality age i.sex i.race i.cancer_type i.elixsum meanvolume teachinghosp medschool cancerprogram SVI i.insurance totaltime, vce (cluster hospitalid)

How do I determine these percentage variabilities? I don't have a lot of background in statistics (plain MD here), and am unsure how to do this. Would appreciate all help!

Example paper: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/36994756/